# Little styling issue on SO mobile

Tags: bug, mobile-web

In the Twitter browser the top menu on at least the profile page is not showing the currently selected item.

Showing

```
 Profile _______ Tags etc
```

The red underline is the currently selected item, but the text is white in white.

[image]

Comment: @CoolGuy actually it's not considered as a duplicate if its on another META and if the question is pertinent to MetaSO

Comment: How come it's not a red circle?